# I am confused about WordPress Structure

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys I am new to editing WordPress. I've done some simple sites but nothing this complex before. I am not sure what `[primaryResources]` means or where I can find it in the code. The code is shown below. Any help here would be great

```
<p class="mnTit">Resources</p>
<p class="mnDesc">the company will continue to offer a full range of indoor and outdoor
LED display products engineered for outstanding image quality and durability</p>
[primaryResources portfolio="3996,3472,3934,2219,3729,3716"][/primaryResources]

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax generally used for shortcodes in WordPress. Shortcodes are piece of code which are written inside of plugin or in functions.php file of your theme, and after adding it to our theme/plugin we can easily use it in page/post.

Reference:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API/
- https://en.support.wordpress.com/shortcodes/